# jQuery Mobile - Open Collapsible-set with URL parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

Using jQuery Mobile, can a panel in the collapsible-set (accordion?) be open by default?  For example, have the second panel, "Title 2", open on page load. I have not found any information on this and would like to do this based on a URL parameter.

Here's the html I have currently:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">
  <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="b">
    <h3>Title 1</h3>
    <div>Text 1 inside here</div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="b">
    <h3>Title 2</h3>
    <div>Text 2 is here</div>
  </div> 
  <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="b">
    <h3>Title 3</h3>
    <div>Text 3 inside this div</div>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/dqmj3/

Comment: If you're still struggling with URL parameter issues, I recently created a [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) which handles jquery mobile URL parameters in a pretty robust way.

Comment: @CameronAskew That's really awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Qm3wb/

Attribute: **`data-collapsed="false"`**

Official documentation : http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#option-collapsed

```
 <div data-role="collapsible-set">
      <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="b" data-collapsed="false">
          <h3>Title 1</h3>
          <div>Text 1 inside here</div>
     </div>
     <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="b">
          <h3>Title 2</h3>
          <div>Text 2 is here</div>
     </div> 
     <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="b">
          <h3>Title 3</h3>
          <div>Text 3 inside this div</div>
     </div>   
</div>
```